# How to get numbers of out a string into a list in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

What regex statement do I need to get each number out of this list and then turn it into a string with each element being the number. For example, if the string is `x = "[899, 908, 3260]"` how do I make this `list = [899, 908, 3260]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think regular expressions is your 1st option to try here.

---

**JSON:** Try to parse it as json:

```
import json
x = "[899, 908, 3260]"
print(json.loads(x))
```

---

**String functions:** Alternatively, some string manipulation:

```
x = "[899, 908, 3260]"
print(list(map(int, x.strip('][').split(', '))))
```

---

**Regex:** If for some reason you definately need regex, you should use `re.findall`:

```
import re
x = "[899, 908, 3260]"
print(list(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", x))))
```

---

All options mentioned above output:

```
[899, 908, 3260]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `eval` function as `eval(x)`. But some say it is exposed one.

Comment: I would in general recommend NOT using `eval` given that it's a lot slower than for example simply parsing json and it also is a security concern

Comment: Also the questions says `using regex`.